# My h1 tag font family suddenly changed from its original font family in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html website, the css is the same for every pages on my website. Today the font of my front page suddenly changed. The original font family was:`font-family: "Alex Brush";` but it changed to some normal font family. I tried adding the `font-family: "Alex Brush";` in the head section of the page but it didn't work. I don't know why it's not showing the same font as on the other pages.

My css:

```
html, body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  height: 100% !important;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
html h1, html h2, html h3, html h4, html h5, body h1, body h2, body h3, body h4, body h5 {
  font-family: "Alex Brush";
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #555;
}
```

Providing my head tag below:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <meta name="author" content="Suave Digital">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets\images\apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets\images\apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets\images\favicon-32x32.png">

    <title>The Nosh Bistro </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- font-awesome.css -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- pe-icon.css -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/css/pe-icon/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/css/pe-icon/helper.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/fonts/flaticon/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fancybox -->
    <link href="assets/javascripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Slick -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/css/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/css/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Animate -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {
    growShrinkLogo()
  };

  function growShrinkLogo() {
    var Logo = document.getElementById("logo")
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 5 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 5) {
      Logo.style.width = '72px';
    } else {
      Logo.style.width = '180px';
    }
  }
</script>

    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font style -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    <style>








    .modal-content{
      width: 440px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    }
    .modal-header{
      height: 5px;
    }
    .peep{
      margin-top: -6px;
    }

    /* @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {


} */

    </style>



  </head>
```

I don't know what happened to my front page. I want my <h1> tags on the front page to show the "Alex Brush" font. Does anyone know the solution to my problem or can anyone tell me how to change the font family in inline tags?

[This](https://thenoshbistro.com) is my HTML page.

Comment: Where did you add the font?? is it google font or through CSS file??

Comment: How did you import your fonts?

Comment: @JoykalInfotech its in the css file

Comment: in your <head>, put your style.css after others .css files.
And <script> are better to put them in the footer not in the <head>.

Comment: and also check for the file and path of the file, it is correct or not.

Comment: Can you show us how did you import the fonts in the css?

Comment: i have posted the css

Comment: Please add the CSS where you have imported the fonts

Comment: But you need to import the font...
From google fonts or something... with <link>  @font-face..?

Comment: @JoykalInfotech i didnt do that, how do i do that

Comment: @ZubairShah Put this in your <head>: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alex+Brush" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: then how are you expecting the font to appear?? You have included the the link for `Roboto` why not Alex O.o

Comment: @aflyzer it still didnt work

Comment: @JoykalInfotech it was working till yesterday but dnt know what happend today

Comment: @ZubairShah I don't understand what's not working. Because you said me this was the right font on you title (on my screenshot). Can you explain what's not working exactly?

Comment: the font is not working in my home page, but its working on other pages

Comment: @ZubairShah what I showed you was on the homepage. Which title are not working? each title? or one particularly?

Comment: none of the titles are working, the problem is in the head section. but dont know whats causing the problem

Comment: can you give a screenshot of your homepage? with the title who are not working pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this two link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

is overriding you default css. So load your css file after these two files or use `!important` along with the style

Also I checked your website. none of the files from your assests are loading, check the server configuration too

[image: CSS files]

Comment: how do i use important

Comment: `font-family: "Alex Brush" !important;`

Comment: I think you can simply put you style.css after all .css files. It'll overwrite the other .css

Comment: this doesn't seem an issue, in her website the font family is indeed "Alex Brush". the issue might be of import.

Comment: I just see your website and your fonts seems to work... Are you sure?

Comment: @brk i tried removing the two external links u said, but it also didnt work

Comment: you have folder named stylesheets/css
I think this can cause some issue. Name it 'stylesheets' and inside create a folder 'css'

Answer (score 0):

You import few times the same files (jquery, bootstrap,...).

On your `<head>` you can remove:

```
<link href="assets\stylesheets\css\menu\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
(the second one not the first)

<script src="assets\stylesheets\css\menu\bootstrap.min.js"></script> (put this 
script on your footer with other script) and change "\" to "/" in the path.


<!-- Font style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And please, in your folders change "stylesheets/css" to "stylesheets" and inside create a new folder with "css" and there put all your files.